# Vanilla kernel build on Rasperry Pi 1 B+

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi

Attempting to build mainline vanilla kernel (4.9) and boot on a Raspberry Pi 1 B+. Have followed instructions [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Upstream_Kernel_Compilation). Currently boot hangs with the following output

> Net: No ethernet found. starting USB...
>   USB0: Core Release: 2.80a
>   scanning bus 0 for devices... 3 USB Device(s) found
>       scanning usb for storage devices... 0 Starage Device(s) found
>   Hit any key to stap autoboot: 0
>   switch to partition #0, OK
>   mmc0 is current device
>   Scanning mmc 0:1
>   Found U-Boot script /boot.scr.uimg
>   reading /boot.scr.uimg 326 bytes read in 25 ms (12.7KiB/s)
>    ## Exectuting script at 02000000 switch to partitions #0, OK
>   mmc0 is current device
>   reading ZImage
>   4064616 bytes read in 389 Ms (10MiB/s)
>   reading bcm2835-rpi-b-plus.dtb
>   7101 bytes read in 31 Ms (223.6KiB/s)
>   Kernel image @ 0x1000000 [ 0x000000 _0x3e0568 ]
>    ## Flattened Device Tree blob at 00000100
>      Booting using the fdt blob at 0x000100
>      Using Device Tree in place at 00000100, end 00004cbc
>
> Starting kernel ...

`boot.scr.uimg` was built using `mkimage` from Ubuntu repositories

> $ mkimage -V
>   mkimage version 2016.01+dfsg1-2ubuntu3
>
> $ mkimage -A arm -O linux -T script -C none -n boot.scr -d boot.scr   boot.scr.uimg

`boot.scr` is as listed in the instructions.

> mmc dev 0
>   setenv fdtfile bcm2835-rpi-b-plus.dtb
>   setenv bootargs earlyprintk console=tty0 console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait
>   fatload mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} zImage
>   fatload mmc 0:1 ${fdt_addr_r} ${fdtfile}
>   bootz ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr_r}

Comment: Following instructions [here](http://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php?title=Raspberry_Pi_Building_Mainline_Kernel) the pi kernel now boots but hangs with (last line of) output  `fb: switching to vc4drmfb from simple`

Comment: This may not be the correct forum for this question, in justification I am attempting to set up a test environment for a device driver so I'm in dev mode :)

Comment: Ensure your console device is correct in bootargs. You have mentioned two devices in console.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried with no 'console' argument and also with `console=tty0`. I also tried replacing the custom kernel with a kernel that boots (using the default boot loader).

Comment: If your still facing problem, use below method to identify whether the kernel is executed or not. http://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing#Debugging_early_boot_problems

Comment: thanks for the tip

Comment: @Tobin, I am facing the same issue, did you find a solution? (the "boot hanging at fb:switching to vc4..." one)

Comment: HI @Sam, no I never resolved this issue. Good luck